# Trouble with simple division in Perl

Tags: perl, division

Trying to calculate Flesch-Kincaid grade levels. What is wrong with the division here?

```
$flesh_grade = 0.39 * ($total_words/$total_sentences) + ($total_syllables/$total_words);
```

Comment: The sign of a good question like yours would be to include instances of all 4 variables and the expected output value. I think your formula is wrong.

Comment: That math works for me. We cannot see your problem. You have to add more details, and a reliable test case.

Comment: That's not the formula for the Flesch–Kincaid grade level.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

[CPAN has a very diverse](https://metacpan.org/) landscape of modules available, and we can find this computation on there as well:

- in the [`Text::Info` module](https://metacpan.org/source/TOREAU/Text-Info-0.01/lib/Text/Info/Readability.pm#L87) we find one way, but this code runs if the [sanity checks](https://metacpan.org/source/TOREAU/Text-Info-0.01/lib/Text/Info/Readability.pm#L32) will pass:

```perl
    my $score = ( ($words_per_sentence * 0.39) + ($syllables_per_word * 11.8) ) - 15.59;
```

- in the [`Lingua::En::Fathom` module](https://metacpan.org/source/KIMRYAN/Lingua-EN-Fathom-1.22/lib/Lingua/EN/Fathom.pm#L637) we find the following:

```perl
    $text->{kincaid} =  (11.8 * $text->{syllables_per_word}) +
         (0.39 * $text->{words_per_sentence}) - 15.59;
```

Comment: Looks like I was using old info. I'll have to find where that new formula is. Thanks. -- David